# CasperJS + Authlogic (Rails) - maintain login session between tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, testing, casperjs, authlogic

I have a single-page app that has a Ruby on Rails backend and uses Authlogic to facilitate user authentication.

I am implementing functional testing using CasperJS and am having a hard time getting login sessions to persist between sessions but also between `thenOpen` commands.

I am running the following command:

```
casperjs --cookies-file=cookies.txt test ../../../foobar/test/casper/login/test.js
```

Here's an example of my current code:

```
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
var x = require('casper').selectXPath

casper.test.begin('Logging in', 2, function suite(test) {
  casper.start('http://localhost:3000/login', function() {
    console.log("Page loaded");

    test.assertExists('form', 'login form is found');
    this.fillSelectors('form', {
      '#email': "foo@bar.com",
      '#password': "foo_bar"
    }, false)

    this.click('#submit')

    casper.thenOpen('http://localhost:3000/my', function() {
      test.assertUrlMatch(this.getCurrentUrl(), 'http://localhost:3000/my', "Logged in and maintained login cookie")
    })
  })

  casper.run(function() {
    test.done();
  });
})
```

While watching my dev log, I can see that the first test (`casper.start`) logs in successfully but after the `thenOpen`, the Authlogic `UserSession` is no longer maintained so PhantomJS gets redirected to `localhost:3000/login`, which is what should happen if there is no logged-in user.

How can I maintain a logged-in session using CasperJS between `thenOpen` but also between multiple test runs? Can I maintain cookies so that the user remains logged-in between tests?

Comment: Maybe it is something to do with local storage/sessions on the SPA? Can you test that bit independently?

Comment: @Rippo I don't believe that is it because it's the Rails end that `requires_user` before certain routes can be hit and the Rails bit that's redirecting back to `localhost:3000/login`. Nothing on the frontend in my SPA would redirect back to there.

Comment: looking at the code you have `this.click` and then doing a `casper.thenOpen`  I would add another step after the form submission and use a `casper.waitForXXXX` . It does look like a timing issue

Comment: @rippo sounds like THAT IS CORRECT! I think we have a winner. You saved me from having to continue clawing my eyeballs out. OK, that's hyperbolic but you might consider posting this in the form of an Answer. My case involved a PHP application but I'm trying to test a ton of Javascript without wearing out mouse and keyboard. With "regular" casper the session persistence seemed to be working automagically, but with test assertions it was not -- until I made it post my login form, then waitForUrl("https://myproject.localhost/wherever-we-redirect-following-login")

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this comment saved the day

> Looking at the code you have `this.click` and then doing a
>   `casper.thenOpen` I would add another step after the form submission and
>   use a `casper.waitForXXXX`.
>
> It does look like a timing issue